# missing type specifier - int assumed and related issues

Tags: c++

I am getting these errors around these defines:

Code:

```
#if defined(POSTER_VER)
 #define DECLARE_COM_PORT_EXT(pErrInfo) \  
   char aname[128]; \
   sprintf(aname, "\\\\.\\COM%d", g_COMPortNumber); \ //First error is here(see below)
   if(!port.OpenPort(aname, CBR_115200, 8, NOPARITY, ONESTOPBIT, HSM_READ_TIMEOUT)) { dppModuleError(dppERR_IO_ERROR, "Ошибка работы с аппаратным ключем").FillErrorStruct(pErrInfo); return dppERR_FAIL ; }
```

Errors:

```
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(30): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(30): error C2365: 'sprintf' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdio.h(357) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(30): error C2078: too many initializers
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(31): error C2059: syntax error : 'if'
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>d:\dppclientmodule\dppclientmodule\cryptography.h(31): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Can someone help me figure out what is happening?

I have added include `<cstdio>` at the top of this file.

Comment: You didn't happen to use that macro at file scope?

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry what do you mean? This macro is used in other cpp files too. It was compiling fine before (As I remember).. don't know what i changed :( that I get these errors..

Comment: How are you using it? The errors look exactly like what you would get if you wrote that code outside of any function. (The `sprintf` line would declare a variable with a missing type and three initialisers, for instance.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes but these are defines, why should I declare them inside function?

Comment: I meant if you wrote the code that the macro expands to outside of any function. It's not about where the definition is, it's about where you use them. (Remember that macros are just text substitutions.)

Comment: @molbdnilo So what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Not use the macro outside of a function? (If that's what you're doing; you still haven't seen fit to divulge that information.)

Comment: The question should show how you are using the macro  (preferably include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your errors are happening in a header, which my first instinct is that you are using a macro inside a class definition instead of a function definition.  I can't say for sure unless you also provide the header file that it is being used in.  Class definitions are not executable code sections, so it assumes when it expands the macro, that you are attempting to define a member called sprintf and initializing the member with the parameters to the function.